# Is there a way to validate a backbone.js model on initialization?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have some code that looks like:

```
var instance = new ModelA(element);
if(instance.isValid()){
    CollectionA.add(instance);
}
```

Is there a better way to write this? Would prefer that either initializing ModelA or adding to CollectionA would fail or throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the constructor.

See [here](http://www.sagarganatra.com/2012/10/backbonejs-model-validation-in.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone has this baked right in.  There is a validate method available in your model code which will get called before any save (You can also do it for set by passing {validate:true}

Here's a snippet from the [backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate):

```
var Chapter = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function(attrs, options) {
        if (attrs.end < attrs.start) {
            return "can't end before it starts";
        }
    }
});
```

If validate returns anything, then the Backbone SAVE won't happen, but if it goes through your validate function cleanly without any returns, then it will go ahead with the save.

Comment: I think the question is not about saving the model, but stopping it's construction. Not sure through.